# How to clear soft keyboard WHILE EditText is in focus?

Tags: android

I have an external button that SHOULD clear/hide the soft keyboard when it is pressed, but the edittext IS IN FOCUS!

All these tips are not for the same use case.

[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

I've even tried clearFocus()

Basically I want to simulate an imeDone event!

Comment: clear soft keyboard mean ?? do u mean hide ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this for your activity in your manifest

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`

Another approach is to move the focus to another view, e.g: transfer the focus to the layout

```
    mylayout.requestFocus()
```